# Is it possible to defer copying data to clipboard at printscreen event?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, printscreen

I need to hide HTML element on a page when someone press the key Printscreen so that the element not to be visible for capturing and not be copied to clipboard.

If I use the way like

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let charCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(charCode == 44) {
        document.querySelector('my-element').style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

the element is still visible at the printscreen event

Maybe there is a way how to defer the copying data to clipboard so that the element can be hidden before the copying via printscreen?

Comment: probably want down not up

Comment: This strategy will not work. If the browser does not have focus, it will not receive key strokes and the whole screen can then be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: change the event listener. You hide it when the event is over.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Or the fact most people use a snipping tool.

Comment: @epascarello keydown doesn't help